# Book: Functional Calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, spectral-theory, advice

Is there a good book that investigates in detail the various kinds of functional calculus?

I'm having now some knowledge about unbounded operators and integration but I would like to understand better functional calculus especially in order to prove Stone's Theorem.

What I'm **not** looking for is an approach to functional calculus via the spectral theorem.

Comment: I would recommend learning basics of $C^{0}$ semigroup theory. Not only will this directly address Stone's Theorem, but it will also give you the tools to deal with more operators on a Banach space. The main tools are Calculus of vector functions, Functional Analysis, and the Laplace Transform. http://www.amazon.com/Semigroups-Operators-Applications-Differential-Mathematical/dp/0387908455/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1402334514&sr=8-1&keywords=pazy

Comment: Will I be able to deal then with problems like time evolution by *unbounded(!)* Hamiltonians $e^{-\imath H}$? Moreover I need to be able to deal with analytic extension of that to complex times $t\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Yes, $C^{0}$ semigroup theory deals with closed, defined linear operators $A$ to obtain a bounded semigroup $T(t)$ of time evolution operators with the $C^{0}$ property that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}T(t)x=x$ for all $x$. Necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ are found so that $\frac{d}{dt}T(t)x=AT(t)x=T(t)Ax$ exists iff $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. The book also deals with analytic semigroups where there is a sectorial extension into time. One of the main ways to obtain $T$ is through a formula based on a familiar Calculus formula for an exponential: $\lim_{n}(I-\frac{t}{n}A)^{-n}x=T(t)x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two books that I recommend are:

- John B. Conway’s *A Course in Functional Analysis*.
- Jiří Blank’s, Pavel Exner’s and Miloslav Havlíček’s *Hilbert Space Operators in Quantum Physics*.

Conway’s book includes a detailed proof of Stone’s Theorem using spectral theory. (For your information, spectral theory is not the only approach to Stone’s Theorem. It can also be proven using the group $ C^{*} $-algebra $ {C^{*}}(\mathbb{R}) $ and some Fourier analysis.) The main highlight of the book, however, is using spectral theory to prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** If $ N $ is a bounded normal operator on a Hilbert space $ \mathcal{H} $, then there is a measure space $ (X,\Sigma,\mu) $ and a function $ \phi \in {L^{\infty}}(X,\Sigma,\mu) $ such that $ N $ is unitarily equivalent to the multiplication operator $ M_{\phi} $ on $ {L^{2}}(X,\Sigma,\mu) $.

Conway claims that this theorem is the optimal form of the spectral theorem for normal bounded operators on a Hilbert space.

The book by the three Czech physicists contains surprisingly rigorous mathematics, and I recommend it because it connects spectral theory with John von Neumann’s attempt to address foundational issues in quantum mechanics. There is a rigorous discussion of Stone’s Theorem and of the time-evolution problem in quantum mechanics (even for a time-dependent Hamiltonian, which is tackled using the Dyson expansion formula).

Comment: "Optimal"...? As in there are other versions...?

Comment: I believe that by ‘optimal’ he means the most concrete version of the Spectral Theorem for Normal Bounded Operators.

Answer (score 1):

*As a suggestion of reading...*

Operator Theory: Weidmann

Spectral Theory: Birman & Solomjak

Semigroup Theory: Engel & Nagel